# Site impression vs. url impression: Search Console as data source in data Studio

Tags: google-search-console, google-data-studio

Could somebody explain me, what is the difference between `site impression` and `url impression`, if i connect Search Console as data source to Data Studio? Look at the screenshot:

[image]

I've compared the data fields of both - they seem to be the same...:( At least i wasn't able to find a difference.

Comment: I would assume that site impression means 'all urls combined' or the 'homepage'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the help docs:

> Google Search Console uses 2 different aggregation methods for
>   reporting on search performance: site impressions and URL impressions.
>   The Search Console connector gives you access to both these methods;
>   however a single data source can only use one of these. (To see your
>   site impressions and URL impressions side by side, create 2 data
>   sources and add both to a single report.)

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7314895?hl=en

There is a table on the following linked page which shows how aggregate metrics are calculated based on property or page
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?visit_id=637016185591726687-3182371645&rd=1#urlorsite